# Auto insert comments backbone in RStudio

Tags: r, comments

What is the easiest way to generate a comment structure for functions in `R` styled according to the [Google R styleguide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml#comments) or [ROxygen](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html) automatically, including:

- a short description
- all paramters of function header (if available)
- the return value (if available)
- allowing to tab through the fields where users needs to input text

something that looks like:

```
sampleFunction<- function(x, y, verbose = TRUE) {
  # [One line description]
  #
  # Args:
  #   x: [Arg description]
  #   y: [Arg description]
  #   verbose: [Arg description]
  #
  # Returns:
  #   [return description]

  return cov(x,y)
}
```

or

```
#' [One line description]
#'
#' @param x [Arg description]
#' @param y [Arg description]
#' @return [return description]
#' @examples
#' add(1, 1)
#' add(10, 1)
add <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you should dig into `roxygen2` style of documenting your functions. Properly formatted function can be used to construct .Rd documentation files automatically. http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/docs.html

Comment: make a generic snippet or ask RStudio to support a keystroke binding for this like they do for roxygen. (shift-alt-cmd-R on OS X for that btw). +1 for Roman's posit. Google's style guide is nice an all but roxygen will get you crunchy goodness when making pkgs and you can make Rds (and, hence, HTML docs) even w/o pkgs.

Comment: Why following Google?

Comment: `ROxygen` and respectively Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R did the trick on windows. Thanks !

Comment: Someone post the roxygen/RStudio/keyboard shortcut as an answer?